# WorkflowElement in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2

Tags: workflow-foundation, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I've downloaded beta 2 of visual studio and followed various tutorials (http://bloggersguides.net/media/p/188.aspx) regarding the creation of custom activities for Workflow. In all of the examples the activity appears to derive from WorkflowElement however it would appear not to exist in beta 2?

I also notice that you can't create a Sequential Workflow Console Application no longer exists in the project templates.

Any ideas where I could find an example on how to create a custom activity like the above tutorial but in beta 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Beta 2 , WorkflowElement goes away, and is replaced with Activity.  Activity is the root type for all units of execution within the world of WF.

here is complete details about changes between Beta1 and Beta 2

http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2009/10/20/wf4-changes-between-beta-1-and-beta-2.aspx

Yes. They have removed the Flowchart Console and the Sequential Console Project Templates. The biggest reasoning being Workflow Team didn't want to portray(mis-guide) Sequence and Flowchart as being the only root activities possible. It is possible to have any composite or a leaf activity to have your root activity for the workflow.

For More details here.
http://blogs.msdn.com/kushals/archive/2009/09/21/wf-4-0-templates-beta2.aspx